# Does Google discourage use of 3rd party Go drivers for cloud sql using?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go

According to [this](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql)

There is a Go library for Cloud SQL.

```
Google Cloud SQL on App Engine:
user@cloudsql(project-id:instance-name)/dbname
```

But according the GAE site, you can (maybe should?) use only java or python to connect to Cloud SQL: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#languages

```
Can I use languages other than Java or Python?
    Only Java and Python are supported for Google Cloud SQL.
```

I'm determining if GAE is a good fit for my Go application.  Is Google discouraging the use of 3rd party libraries to connect to Cloud SQL?

Not being able to use Cloud SQL would be a deal breaker for me and will have me looking for another platform to host my Go application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine Go SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/)
>
> This document describes how to use Google Cloud SQL instances with the
>   App Engine Go SDK.
>
> [Cloud SQL with Go-MySQL-Driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/XZwBvrFCrQs)
>
> We would like to add support for Cloud SQL to
>   github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.
>
> There shouldn't be much to do. The appengine/cloudsql package [1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/)
>   provides a Dial function that takes a CloudSQL instance name and
>   returns a net.Conn; you just have to arrange for your mysql driver to
>   call that (or have some way of taking a net.Conn).
>
> You could follow what we did for ziutek's mymysql package [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/XZwBvrFCrQs).

Why do you think you have will have a problem?

Comment: Having this "Only Java and Python are supported for Google Cloud SQL." in their docs threw me off a bit.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use 3rd packages, here is the document in Go specific App Engine API:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference

> Applications should use this package through database/sql: Select a
>   **pure Go MySQL driver that supports this package**, and use sql.Open with
>   protocol "cloudsql" and an address of the CloudSQL instance. The exact
>   format of the second argument to sql.Open is driver-dependent; consult
>   the driver's documentation for details.

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "<some mysql package>"
```

So I think "" can be https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql